# Finding which of the 4 boxes best hold the dimensions of item X

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

Friends;

So lets say I have 4 box sizes with their dimension in a list. I also have an array of objects to fit in the boxes with their own dimensions. I only want to fit one item in one box so i want the box that fits the item the best.

Under my "box that fits" column, I would like a formula or something that can look down the item dimensions and compare them to the box dimensions and find whatever box works best with item, then display the name from column A.

So if i have an item that 9x9x9 and a box that is 10x10x10, my sheet will choose that box because the item is just less than the box size.

This chart is an example of how I kinda have things set up.

[image]

Can anyone help me out with this?

I appreciate any assistance. Let me know if i need to clear anything up.

Comment: This would be easier (for me, at least) if the boxes and the items were 2 different tables in MS Access. Can I use Access for my answer, or are you only interested in Excel answers?

Comment: I only have access to excel, unfortunately. If it needs to be broken up that's fine. I just did it like this for ease of explanation.

Comment: Can an item be reoriented (e.g. can an 8x5x3 item fit in an 6x10x4 box)?

Comment: length and width can but not height. They have to sit flat.

Comment: you also can not turn the box?

Comment: The length could become the width but the height needs to stay the height.

Comment: If there were two boxes of similar size that the object would fit into, how would you choose between them? Smallest area (length X width) maybe, or smallest volume?

Comment: At that point it wouldn't really matter. The closest fit is the best fit. Those box sizes listed are the actual sizes so they aren't incredibly close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've switched item 4444 length and width (so always `length >= width`).

for a simple "first box to fit in" you can use:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$5,MATCH(1,(B$2:B$5>=F2)*(C$2:C$5>=G2)*(D$2:D$5>=H2),0))
```

to get the "box with the least waste of space" you can use:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$5,MATCH(MIN(IF((B$2:B$5>=F2)*(C$2:C$5>=G2)*(D$2:D$5>=H2),B$2:B$5*C$2:C$5*D$2:D$5-PRODUCT(F2:H2),1E+100)),IF((B$2:B$5>=F2)*(C$2:C$5>=G2)*(D$2:D$5>=H2),B$2:B$5*C$2:C$5*D$2:D$5-PRODUCT(F2:H2),1E+100),0))
```

> This are array formulas and need to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>!

[image]

*The table to the right is just for showing the unused space and is not used*
*All formulas are written for `I2` and can be copied down*

**EDIT**

without sorting and the case where no box fits, it gets a bit complex and looks like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$5,MATCH(MIN(IF(((B$2:B$5>=G2)*(C$2:C$5>=H2)+(B$2:B$5>=H2)*(C$2:C$5>=G2))*(D$2:D$5>=I2),B$2:B$5*C$2:C$5*D$2:D$5,1E+100),1E+99),IF(((B$2:B$5>=G2)*(C$2:C$5>=H2)+(B$2:B$5>=H2)*(C$2:C$5>=G2))*(D$2:D$5>=I2),B$2:B$5*C$2:C$5*D$2:D$5,1E+100),0)),"")
```

But if you can set the order of the boxes from smallest volume to largest, then this will do:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$5,MATCH(TRUE,((B$2:B$5>=G2)*(C$2:C$5>=H2)+(B$2:B$5>=H2)*(C$2:C$5>=G2))*(D$2:D$5>=I2)>0,0)),"")
```

And if you set the order of the boxes from smallest volume to largest while also having always `length >= width`, then this will do:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$5,MATCH(1,(B$2:B$5>=G2)*(C$2:C$5>=H2)*(D$2:D$5>=I2),0)),"")
```

Comment: Was working on a similar answer. Note that you can just calculate shortest and longest length in an different column simply, by  using `=IF(G2<H2; G2; H2)` for shortest length/width, and `=IF(G2<H2; H2; G2)` for longest length/width

Comment: Thanks so much! This one looks like it's going to do everything i needed it to do. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth using helper cells it would be much easier... but i'll avoid them if possible... another way would be the change of the both `((B$2:B$5>=F2)*(C$2:C$5>=G2)*` to `(((B$2:B$5>=F2)*(C$2:C$5>=G2)+(B$2:B$5>=G2)*(C$2:C$5>=F2))*`... no sorting needed and also no helper cells... (for the second formula) :P

Comment: As an addition: any way we can get this to display "  " if there is no data in the source cells? I'm going to have a sheet full of these and it seems to default to the smallest box size when '0' is detected.

Comment: Yes, of course. I usually answer with helper cells (as it's more clear exactly what my code is doing), and implement without them if i'm going to use the code, but it's nice that you do avoid them altogether.

Comment: @mystic_muffin use `=IF(ISERROR([first formula]),"",[second formula])`... unfortunately, the second formula will not error out because of the `MIN`-part... but the first formula will do the trick :D