# Finding combination of 3 values in range of data

Tags: excel

I have 258 boxe types with the height, width and depth of each one.

I want to be able to type in the dimension of an item, and then have Excel return all the boxes which this item will fit.

In a perfect world I would like it to prompt me:

1: Measures 1 and type 1 measure of the item

2: Measures 2 and type the other measure of the item

3: Measures 3 and type in the last measure of the item.

After which Excel should return all box types in which the item will fit.

Sample data:

[image: Data example]

[image: Input]

Comment: Please ask a specific question and post any code you have tried.

Comment: This was asked recently... However, a quick search on here, which you may have found when **you** looked, gives https://stackoverflow.com/q/45598673/4961700

Comment: Thannks… but the one you linked is for 2 dimensions, I want all 3 dimensions to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming :
Height = Column A , Width = Column B, Depth = Column C, BoxName = Column D. Measure1 at `F2`, Measure2 at `G2`, Measure3 at `H2`.

You may put `=IF(A2>=$F$2,1,0)*IF(B2>=$G$2,1,0)*IF(C2>=$H$2,1,0)` in `E2`, drag downwards, then use this column to 'filter' the matched boxes. ( :